# Доступ к компонентам Vuforia в Unity3D

Tags: unity3d, vuforia

Пытаюсь установить библиотеку Vuforia в Unity3D 5.6.6f2. Сделал Import Package -> Custom Package -> vuforia-unity-6-2-10.unitypackage. Пакет скачивал с официального сайта. После этого в строке главного меню появилась вкладка Vuforia, но где дальше искать её компоненты, не пойму. Вкладки Prefab не нахожу. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Training/getting-started-with-vuforia-in-unity.html

Comment: Там указано, как добавить Vuforia сразу при установке Unity. Мне же надо добавить библиотеку к уже установленной среде, т.е. через Import Package. В других местах говорилось, что в таком случае должна появиться вкладка Asserts -> Vuforia -> Prefab, но у меня таковой нет.

Comment: Вы указали в настройках проекта, что нужно использовать Vuforia AR?

Comment: В окне Player Settings поставил галку Virtual Reality Supported, но в списке Virtual Reality SDKs нет Vuforia.

Comment: Может проблема в том, что у меня Unity3D 32 битная?